# Highlighter InkCanvas

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, silverlight

I have used `IsHighlighter` property of `InkCanvas` to create highlighter tool . 
In real life when we use highlighter it highlights on the top of our notebooks or books writing , 
but in `InkCanvas` i am not able to highlight on the top of Ink which i have previously drawn . 
I am creating application which have pen as well highlighter tool ,
 now if i have to highlight some thing which i have drawin onto 
`InkCanvas` using pen highliter goes down to Ink .

[image: Check this image, in which i have pen as well highlighter]

here highlighter is highlighting bellow my pen's drawing.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the ZOrder of strokes there is a workaround for that: [Using multiple InkCanvases](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tabletandtouch/thread/3f2c84f3-3a7b-43ae-b837-8108e1b0cffe)

I am a bit disappointed by this; I'd expect the ability to move strokes on top. I even tried to manipulate the order of the Strokes in the StrokeCollection but to no avail.

So I found a more intuitive way: just do **not** use the IsHighlighter property but instead make a DrawingAttributes object with a Transparent color:

```
private DrawingAttributes _highLighter =
    new DrawingAttributes { 
        Color = Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 255, 0),
        IsHighlighter = false, 
        Width = 20, Height = 20 
    };
```

The strokes with this color will be added on top just like a normal highlighter and when you switch back to a pen(cil) you will overwrite the highlights, just as in real life.

Comment: If we create highlighter using this technique then ,
When we will highligh again on highlighted area then color becomes dark and dark , it does not happen with if we use IsHighlighter property . 
It should take if it is drawing on previously highlighted area .
Thanks

Comment: On real paper, if you use a highlighter multiple times it will become darker. So it depends on the effect you want. that is why I added both options: two inkcanvases or using a transparent color.